# apt-cache unmet shows non-existent packages

Tags: apt, package-management, dependencies, apt-cache

Running `apt-cache unmet` outputs a 1.2 MB file of missing dependencies of packages, none of which exist (the packages themselves).

This is possibly due to restoring old configurations to a fresh install of Ubuntu. I have tried removing, cleaning and purging any related configuration.

Can confirm that the packages do not exist. Any suggestions to make apt-cache know that I don't have these packages already, hence no dependencies flags should exist ?

Comment: On my system, it's about 4MB output (>87.000 lines)... I guess this command is designed to print all unmet dependencies of all *installable* packages, instead of only those packages which are actually installed.

Comment: @ByteCommander I have tested on a live install and indeed it is the case. It has generated about 1.3MB of output. I'll close the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On my system, it's about 4MB output (>87.000 lines).
<sub>Found out using `apt-cache unmet | wc -c` for number of bytes and `apt-cache unmet | wc -l` for number of lines.</sub>

I did not learn much from having a quick glance at the source code, but I strongly guess this command is designed to print all unmet dependencies of *all installable packages*, instead of only those packages which are actually installed.

The manpage `man apt-cache` is in my opinion not unambiguously worded, but here are the important snippets:

```
   unmet
       unmet displays a summary of all unmet dependencies in the package cache.

   -i, --important
       Print only important dependencies; for use with unmet and depends. Causes only Depends and Pre-Depends relations to
       be printed. Configuration Item: APT::Cache::Important.
```

So you can also narrow down the output somehow if you add the `-i` argument. I am not sure what exactly this filters out, but it results in less than about 10%, roughly 7.000 lines in my case.

```
$ apt-cache unmet -i | wc -l
7096
```

Comment: That's indeed the case, `man apt-cache` confirms that.

Comment: It is indeed the case as you have said. Thanks for the `wc -l` though ;)

Comment: @egy See my edit about the `-i` option.